# How to send data to view from form after asking for confirmation?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal

I created a simple form where I'm asking for user input and then posting that to the database. Now I would like the user to confirm the data in form is correct, and for that I'm using a `Bootstrap modal`.

How can I send the data from the form to the view when pressing the `'OK' button` on the modal.

I'm new to the `Django framework`, and maybe there is another better way without using bootstrap modals.

Form:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    report_title = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_report_titles())
    report_link = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

Html file:

```
<form class="w-100" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label class="pl-0 mt-auto mr-2">Report&nbsp;Name</label>
    <select name="report_title" class="form-control report-name">
        <option selected>Select report</option>
        {% for name in report_names %}
        <option>{{ name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <div class="my-1 col-lg-12 float-left pl-0">
        <label>Report Link</label>
        <input class="form-control bg-white" type="text" id="report" name="report_link">
    </div>
    <input id="confirm" value="Save" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="btn btn-outline-success" />
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class=" modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Confirmation</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Make sure you have the right title and link.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View:

```
def report_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                report_title = form.cleaned_data['report_title']
                report_link = form.cleaned_data['report_link']
                new_report = Report(title = report_title, link = report_link)
                new_report.save()
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but without code it's hard to see the one you chose. If I had to do this I would intercept the submit action in JS to show a modal with the recap and then post the form programmatically once it's validated.

Comment: @Leogout I created the form according to the Django docs. It's in the simplest way possible. Can you show me some steps on what could I do please.

Comment: @PlarentHaxhidauti If your form view is working correct then this problem isn't about django actually. This is your bootstrap and some JS. Use some JavaScript, as soon as the 'ok' button is clicked you can submit your form via javascript.

Comment: @xxbinxx This is the part I'm struggling with. How can I submit my form via javascript to my view.

Comment: show your current code and we can help

Comment: @PlarentHaxhidauti there's nothing to stuggle about if you understand the flow. Ok leaving it aside. Bootstrap model se secondary here. First make sure you're able to submit your form and save data without using the bootstrap Modal. I mean you have a django form and it's displayed in the template, this form has 'submit' button. When you hit this submit button. Are you able to receive and save your form data ??

Comment: @xxbinxx I posted the code I have, yes I can save the data in the DB, no issue there. I just want when the user presses the Save button, a popup to show as a confirmation dialog and when the user presses Confirm, then the data is send to the view.

Comment: @HenryM I just posted the code I have now.

Comment: and how are you opening your bootstrap modal?

Comment: @xxbinxx I just posted on how I open the modal

Comment: @PlarentHaxhidauti check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update your code with these lines, add `id="exampleForm"`.

start form tag with

```
<form class="w-100" action="" id="exampleForm" method="post">
```

Replace Save button with (add `id="save"`):

```
<button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

and finally add this script at the bottom to submit your form when `save` is clicked:

```
<script>
$("#save").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#exampleForm").submit();
});
</script>
```

also I feel your `view` is not written correctly. It should be something like this, I'm not sure what you're trying to do:

```
def report_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            form = ReportForm(request.POST)
            report_title = form.cleaned_data['report_title']
            report_link = form.cleaned_data['report_link']
            new_report = Report(title = report_title, link = report_link)
            new_report.save()
```

Let me know if you still need help

Comment: It's working now, and my view is same as what you suggested I just missed one tab on the whole second 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

This needs changing because you're not giving any values.

```
  <select name="report_title" class="form-control report-name">
     <option selected>Select report</option>
     {% for name in report_names %}
     <option>{{ name }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

Try:

```
  <select name="report_title" class="form-control report-name">
     <option selected>Select report</option>
     {% for name in report_names %}
     <option value="{{name.pk}}">{{ name }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

where name.pk is the value relating to the choices.

Also, if you change your form to a ModelForm you can just do:

```
if form.is_valid():
    new_report = form.save()
```